# how to change style color of arrows in Vue Slick Carousel?

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, carousel, slick.js

I use [vue-slick-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slick-carousel) for a carousel in my project.
I want to change the color of the arrows without changing the style in the module of this package.
I added this code in the main CSS file and this not working for me

```
        .slick-prev:before,
            .slick-next:before {
                font-size: 20px;
                line-height: 1;

                opacity: 0.75;
                color: red !important;

                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Funny I've had the same problem a while ago, my problem was that I had defined my styles in a scoped style tag.

Try this code in a global style tag:

```
button.slick-prev:before, button.slick-next:before {
      background-color: red !important;
}
```